# How to profile the number of global memory transactions for cuda kernels?

Tags: cuda, profiling, gpu

How to enable profiling for "uncached_global_load_transaction" counter in cuda command-line profiler？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line profiler is controlled using the following environment variables -

```
COMPUTE_PROFILE: is set to either 1 or 0 (or unset) to enable or disable profiling.
COMPUTE_PROFILE_CONFIG: is used to specify a config file for enabling performance counters in the GPU and various other options.
COMPUTE_PROFILE_LOG: is set to the desired file path for profiling output.
```

In your case you can set above environment variables as -

```
COMPUTE_PROFILE=1
COMPUTE_PROFILE_CONFIG=config.txt
COMPUTE_PROFILE_LOG=profiler_output.txt
```

`config.txt` must contain an entry `uncached_global_load_transaction`.

Comment: Thanks. I did the samething, but the profiler can't identify the uncached_global_load_transaction option. Maybe my card doesn't support it.