# cudaStreamSynchronize vs CudaDeviceSynchronize vs cudaThreadSynchronize

Tags: cuda

What is the difference between these three functions, especially the last two? The library manual says

> Note that this function is deprecated because its name does not
>   reflect its behavior. Its functionality is similar to the
>   non-deprecated function cudaDeviceSynchronize(), which should be used
>   instead.

But not very sure what does it mean.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

These are all *barriers*.  Barriers prevent code execution beyond the barrier until some condition is met.

1. [cudaDeviceSynchronize()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g32bdc6229081137acd3cba5da2897779) halts execution in the CPU/host thread (that the cudaDeviceSynchronize was issued in) until the GPU has finished processing all previously requested cuda tasks (kernels, data copies, etc.)
2. [cudaThreadSynchronize()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__THREAD__DEPRECATED_1g6e0c5163e6f959b56b6ae2eaa8483576) as you've discovered, is just a deprecated version of `cudaDeviceSynchronize`.  Deprecated just means that it still works for now, but it's recommended not to use it (use cudaDeviceSynchronize instead) and in the future, it may become unsupported.  But `cudaThreadSynchronize`() and `cudaDeviceSynchronize`() are similar.
3. [cudaStreamSynchronize()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__STREAM_1geb3b2f88b7c1cff8b67a998a3a41c179) is similar to the above two functions, but it prevents further execution in the CPU host thread until the GPU has finished processing all previously requested cuda tasks *that were issued in the referenced stream*.  So `cudaStreamSynchronize`() takes a stream id as its only parameter.  cuda tasks issued in other streams may or may not be complete when CPU code execution continues beyond this barrier.

Comment: The Cuda documenation (as quoted in the question) states `Its functionality is similar`. They do not say it is the same, only similar, so how can you know they are identical? Can you cite any source?

Comment: I changed "basically identical" to "similar".    The important takeaway is that it is deprecated and the documentation recommends using `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, when moving from the deprecated one to the new name, it would be good to know how they differ or whether the documentation writer was just afraid of taking a stance that they were the same other than having a different function name.